# How to concatenate and sum random comma separated values with case statement?

Tags: sql, sum, concatenation, case

I have a view which is a simple case statement.

```
SELECT CAST(
         CASE 
              WHEN [value] = 'Canadian' and fieldid = 78
                 THEN 5
              WHEN [value] = 'US' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 3
              WHEN [value] = 'UK' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1
              When [value] = 'Australia' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1
              When [value] = 'Israel' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1 
              When [value] = 'Others' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1
```

Everything is ok so far when a column has the matching value it gives it the point but sometimes the column can hold random multiple values separated by comma. How can i calculate that?
This is what happens now.

```
 +----+------------------+--------+
 | ID | Value            | Points |
 +----+------------------+--------+
 |  1 | Canadian         |   5    |
 |  2 | UK               |   1    |
 |  3 | Canadian,UK      |   0    |
 +----+----------+----------------+
```

Expected result

```
 +----+------------------+--------+
 | ID | Value            | Points |
 +----+------------------+--------+
 |  1 | Canadian         |   5    |
 |  2 | UK               |   1    |
 |  3 | Canadian,UK      |   6    |
 +----+----------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SQL Server 2017 you could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, t.[value],
         SUM(CASE 
              WHEN s.[value] = 'Canadian' and fieldid = 78
                 THEN 5
              WHEN s.[value] = 'US' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 3
              WHEN s.[value] = 'UK' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1
              When s.[value] = 'Australia' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1
              When s.[value] = 'Israel' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1 
              When s.[value] = 'Others' and fieldid = 78
                 Then 1
           END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS Points
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.[value], ',') s
ORDER BY t.id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=b816181bac4653248dd02136a088602c)**

Storing multiple values in single column violates 1st Normal Form and it should be avoided.

---

It could be simplified to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, t.[value],
             SUM(CASE 
                  WHEN s.[value] = 'Canadian' and fieldid = 78
                     THEN 5
                  WHEN s.[value] = 'US' and fieldid = 78
                     Then 3
                  WHEN s.[value] IN ('UK', 'Australia' , 'Israel', 'Others') 
                       and fieldid = 78
                     Then 1
               END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS Points
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.[value], ',') s
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just with `CASE` and `LIKE`:

```
SELECT ((CASE WHEN ',' + [value] + ',' LIKE '%,Canadian,%' and fieldid = 78
             THEN 5 ELSE 0
         END) +
        (CASE WHEN ',' + [value] + ',' LIKE '%,US,%' and fieldid = 78
             THEN 3 ELSE 0
         END) +
        (CASE WHEN ',' + [value] + ',' LIKE '%,UK,%' and fieldid = 78
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END) +
        (CASE WHEN ',' + [value] + ',' LIKE '%,Australia,%' and fieldid = 78
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END) +
        (CASE WHEN ',' + [value] + ',' LIKE '%,Israel,%' and fieldid = 78
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END) +
        (CASE WHEN ',' + [value] + ',' LIKE '%,Others,%' and fieldid = 78
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END)
       ) as val
```

That said, I strongly, strongly, strongly discourage you from storing multiple values in a single column.  SQL is designed to store a single value in columns (at least for the scalar column types and a string is a scalar type).

You should have a separate table that is a junction/association table with one row per entity and country.

EDIT:  If you were using SQL Server 2017 or had a split string function, I would advise you to do it this way:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.[value], COALESCE(s.points, 0) as points
FROM tab t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.[value] = 'Canadian' THEN 5
                      WHEN s.[value] = 'US' THEN 3
                      WHEN s.[value] IN ('UK', 'Australia' , 'Israel', 'Others') THEN 1
                 END) AS Points
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.[value], ',') s
      WHERE t.fieldid = 78
     ) s
ORDER BY t.id;
```